# How do you infer topics on a supervised LDA/LLDA in mallet?

Tags: lda, supervised-learning, inference, mallet

I used MALLET's LabeledLDA class to make a model, that I have saved in a binary file. I want to take my test data and see how well the model predicts the appropriate label.

I can only find documentation for the unsupervised LDA [here](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/topics.php) under the infer topics section.

this is the command I'm using:

```
mallet infer-topics --inferencer fold_0_train.bin  --input fold_0_test.txt
```

I'm getting a Java end of file exception.

How do you test the LLDA with test data?
What format should the test data be in?